# Simplify the expression (0,5+0,5i)^7 as much as possible

Tags: complex-numbers

First I wrote the complex number in polar form:

`0,5+i0,5`= r`(cosv+isinv)`

tan(v)=`0,5/0,5` =1      v=45
r=√`(`0,5^2+0,5^2`)`=√0,5

--> 0,5+i0,5= **√0,5(cos45+isin45)**

Then I used de Moivres formula and got the following answer

`(0,5+i0,5)^7`= (√0,5)^7 (cos(45×7)+ isin(45×7)=

(√0,5)/8(cos315+isin315)= 0,0625+(-i0,0625)= **0,0625-i0,0625.**

Does anyone think the answer should be diffrent?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It basically looks correct but would be easier to read with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Yes I agree, I'll try to use it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Binomial theorem.

$(\frac 12 + \frac 12i)^7 = \frac 1{2^7}(1+i)^7 = \frac 1{128}(1 + 7i + \frac {7*6}2i^2 + \frac {7*6*5}{2*3} i^3 + \frac {7*6*5}{2*3}i^4 + \frac {7*6}{2} i^5+7i^6 + i^7)=$

$ \frac 1{128}(1 + 7i - 21 - 35i + 35 + 21i -7 -i)=\frac 1{128}(8-8i)=\frac 1{16}-\frac 1{16}i$

..... which was way too hard....

2) polar coordinates.

$\frac 12 + \frac 12 i = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$.

$r = \sqrt {(\frac 12)^2 + (\frac 12)^2} = \sqrt{\frac 12}=\frac {\sqrt 2}2=(\frac 12)^{\frac 12}$ and $\theta = \arctan \frac {\frac 12}{\frac 12}=\arctan 1 = \frac {\pi} 4$.

(You really should stop relying on decimals and you should start using radians.)

So $(\frac 12 + \frac 12i)^7 = (\frac {1}{2})^{\frac 72}(\cos \frac{7\pi}4 + i \sin \frac {7\pi}4)=$

$(\frac {1}{2})^{\frac 72}(\frac {\sqrt 2}2 - \frac {\sqrt 2}2i)=(\frac 12)^{\frac 72}((\frac 12)^{\frac 12} - i (\frac 12)^{\frac 12})= \frac 1{2^4}(1-i)=$

$\frac 1{16} - \frac 1{16}i$.